# Why isn't my weighted median filter working properly?

Tags: python, image-processing, weighted-average

I am trying to implement a weighted median filter in Python. It seems to color correct the whole image rather than filter the salt-and-pepper noise that I added to the original image.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def add_zg_impuls(img, ratio):
    H, W, ch = img.shape
    length = int(H*W*ch*ratio)
    lin = np.random.randint(0, H, length)
    col = np.random.randint(0, W, length)
    val = np.random.randint(0, 2, length)
    img_impuls = img.copy()
    for i in range(length):
        img_impuls[lin[i], col[i], np.random.randint(0, 3)] = 255 * val[i]
    return img_impuls


def apply_L_filter(img, size, weights):
    h, w,c = img.shape
    cap = size // 2
    new_img = np.zeros_like(img)
   
    for i in range(cap, h - cap):
        for j in range(cap, w - cap):
            for canal in range(c):
                vec = img[i-cap:i+cap+1, j-cap:j+cap+1, canal]
                values = np.reshape(vec, size*size)
                sorted_values = np.sort(values)
                weighted_values = sorted_values * weights.flatten()
                new_img[i, j, canal] = np.sum(weighted_values)
    
    return new_img

image = io.imread("tiffany.bmp")
plt.figure(), plt.imshow(image), plt.title("Imagine originala"), plt.show()

image_noise= add_zg_impuls(image,0.1)
plt.figure(), plt.imshow(image_noise), plt.title("Imagine alterata 10%"), plt.show()

filter_size = 5
filter_weights = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

filtered_image = apply_L_filter(image_noise, filter_size, filter_weights)
plt.figure(), plt.imshow(filtered_image), plt.title("Imagine filtrata ponderat"), plt.show()
```

[image: Results so far]

Comment: You need to normalise the image after applying the filter (divide by 35 I think). You might want to test using an unweighted median value just to check the rest of the code. That ought to still work even if the filtering normalisation is awry.

Comment: Thank you! I tried normalising the image after the filter is applied but kind of looks the same to me... I also tried with no weight values and it works that way..

Comment: Looks more like a weighted mean than a median. Median selects the middle value, not the average.

Comment: For people who would like to reproduce: https://www.hlevkin.com/hlevkin/06testimages.htm

Comment: How is multiplying the sorted neighborhood by weights and summing the results a median? Maybe if the weights were normalized you could call it “medianish-mean” or something. But this is far from anything related to a weighted median. You should add each value to an array multiple times according to the weight (if the weight is 3, add it 3 times), then you sort all values and pick the one in the middle. This way you weigh the values in the middle of the neighborhood more heavily than those in the periphery.